# Criteria query on part of a composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-annotations

We recently ran across a bug in our software due to a missing `@Id` annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table (name ="PATRONQRSPLANS")
//@IdClass(PatronPlan.class) <-- this was missing
public class Balance {

    @Transient
    private String kind;

    @Transient
    private String planName;

    @Transient
    private PlanCategory planCategory;

    @Id
    @Column(name="PATRONID")
    private int patronId;

    //@Id    <--- and this was missing
    @Column(name="PLANID")
    private int planId;

    @Column(name="BALANCE")
    private int balance;

    @Column(name="ENDDATE")
    private Date expirationDate;

    public Balance() {
        this.kind = "balance";
    }

    public Balance(int balance, int planId, Date expirationDate) {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.planId = planId;
        this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
        this.kind = "balance";
    }

    public int getPatronId() {
        return patronId;
    }

    public void setPatronId(int patronId) {
        this.patronId = patronId;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public int getPlanId() {
        return planId;
    }

    public void setPlanId(int planId) {
        this.planId = planId;
    }

    public String getPlanName() {
        return planName;
    }

    public void setPlanName(String planName) {
        this.planName = planName;
    }

    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public Date getExpirationDate() {
        return expirationDate;
    }

    public void setExpirationDate(Date expirationDate) {
        this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
    }

    public PlanCategory getPlanCategory() {
        return planCategory;
    }

    public void setPlanCategory(PlanCategory planCategory) {
        this.planCategory = planCategory;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the table has a primary key constraint on both planId and patronId, so I need a composite key. The query below (without the commented out annotations above), for a patron that has 2 different plans, will return 2 copies of the same plan instead of 2 different ones.

```
public List<Balance> getBalancesByPatronId(int patronId) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Balance> query = builder.createQuery(Balance.class);

    Root<Balance> s = query.from(Balance.class);
    query.select(s);
    query.where(builder.equal(s.get("patronId"), patronId));

    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

To remedy this, I added an `@Id` and `@IdClass` annotation as commented out above, as well as creating this class:

```
public class PatronPlan implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3518083815234439123L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="PATRONID")
    private int patronId;

    @Id
    @Column(name="PLANID")
    private int planId;

    public int getPatronId() {
        return patronId;
    }

    public void setPatronId(int patronId) {
        this.patronId = patronId;
    }

    public int getPlanId() {
        return planId;
    }

    public void setPlanId(int planId) {
        this.planId = planId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!this.getClass().isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) return false;

        PatronPlan other = (PatronPlan) obj;
        return Objects.equals(patronId, other.getPatronId()) && Objects.equals(planId, other.getPlanId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(patronId, planId);
    }
```

}

But now I get a NullPointerException in my critera query on the statement
`s.get("patronId")`, because patronId is not showing up as a declaredAttribute, though it does seem to be showing up in the id information.

Is my composite key setup correct and how to I query for part of a composite key using the criteria api?

If it wasn't clear above, the goal is to be able to get all the Balance objects with a given `patronId`, even though `patronId` is only part of the composite key.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain if this is correct, but it seems to be working. Is this correct? My knowledge of hibernate is limited.

```
public List<Balance> getBalancesByPatronId(int patronId) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Balance> query = builder.createQuery(Balance.class);

    Metamodel metaModel = getEntityManager().getMetamodel();

    SingularAttribute<Balance, Integer> patronIdAttr = 
        (SingularAttribute<Balance, Integer>) metaModel.entity(Balance.class)
        .getIdClassAttributes().toArray()[0];

    Root<Balance> s = query.from(Balance.class);
    query.select(s);
    query.where(builder.equal(s.get(patronIdAttr), patronId));

    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```